# Nebular creating custom registration

Tags: angular, forms, nebular

So i have to create a bit different registration from nebular standard registration. I have created custom form validation and because of this standard registration system doesn't work for me. As I think I have to send request to backend manually using HttpClient. But I can't implement it because I'm extending my register component with NbRegisterComponent. Here is my code:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NbRegisterComponent} from '@nebular/auth';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss'],
})

export class NgxRegisterComponent extends NbRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(15),
      ]),
      lastName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(15),
      ]),
      email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
      ]),
      age: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(18),
        Validators.max(100),
      ]),
      sex: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
      role: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
      pass: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(10),
      ]),
      passRepeat: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        // PasswordMatchValidator.passwordMatch,
      ]),
      checkbox: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.requiredTrue,
      ]),
    });
  }

  registerSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log('form submitted: ', this.form);
      const formData = {...this.form.value};

      console.log('form data: ', formData);
    }
  }
}
```

All is working in here, but when I'm trying to add constructor It fails.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, service: NbAuthService, @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options:{}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router) {
    super(PARAMS_HERE);
}
```

If it doesn't works, try this second way:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private YourCustomAuthService: YourCustomAuthService, service: NbAuthService, @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options:{}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router) {
    super(PARAMS_HERE);
}
```